# Logstash grok regex pattern matching of arbitrary number of characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a grok pattern that captures *n* number of characters. For example I want to capture the following in a single field,  which is 17 characters in length:

```
12/30/16 04:40 PM
```

I tried using the grok debugger with the following but it didn't appear to work:

```
 (?<some_id>\[.\]{17})
```

Thanks and Happy New Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash escapes characters which means they are treated literally, here: `\[` is treated as opening bracket and not as an opening for the character class. In the given example opening bracket [ is not part of the input string hence no match will occur.

I've modified slightly your pattern and tested on : https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

```
(?<some_id>.{17})
```

Output:

```
{
  "some_id": [
    [
      "12/30/16 04:40 PM"
    ]
  ]
}
```